# How to get the current model name or use other method at runtime in Prisma ORM

Tags: orm, prisma

New feature has been included In prisma ORM version `4.9.0` [Doc Link](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/client-extensions/model)

After update `schema.prisma` as follow

```js
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["clientExtensions"]
}
```

How do we get model name at runtime and use other method also at runtime

```js
const { PrismaClient, Prisma } = require("@prisma/client");

const db = new PrismaClient().$extends({
  client: {
    log: (s) => console.log(s),
    async useLog() {
      // how to use log function
      // here

    },
  },
  model: {
    $allModels: {
      log: (s) => console.log(s),
      async find(id, option = {}) {
        // how to get current model name in runtime
        
       // or use other function here
      },
    },
  },
});

module.exports = { db };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

```js
const { PrismaClient, Prisma } = require("@prisma/client");

const db = new PrismaClient().$extends({
  client: {
    log: (s) => console.log(s),
    async useLog() {
      const ctx = Prisma.getExtensionContext(this);
      ctx.log("test"); // it will print "test" on console 
    },
  },
  model: {
    $allModels: {
      log: (s) => console.log(s),
      async find(id, option = {}) {
        const ctx = Prisma.getExtensionContext(this);
        // here is log the current runtime model name
        console.log(ctx.name);

        // here we can use other method of prisma model
        return ctx.findUniqueOrThrow({
          where: {
            id,
          },
          ...option,
        });
      },
    },
  },
});

module.exports = { db };
```

Now we can use `find` method in all model just like

```js
const { db } = require("@app/src/utils/db");

const teacher = await db.teacher.find(teacherId);
const student = await db.student.find(studentId);
```